# Is it possible to fix such level of corruption in a buggy audio recording (sound distorded-choppy-Laggy)

Tags: audio-recording, distortion, bugs, fix

You'll find [here](https://soundcloud.com/user-959579441/corrupted-audio-recording) a part of that corrupted audio file. I don't know how to describe this kind of distortion, so I did not find any thread talking about that specific kind of corruption. (I found a lot of thread showing how to fix corrupted file that doesn't open, or that are slightly distorded.)

It has been recorded with a samsung app phone, which sometimes did that (It's a 5mn recording). (I'm not using that app anymore)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can fix that unless you have a fully equipped studio for forensic analysis, very good ears and a LOT of time.

What you're hearing has a number of problems. The greatest is that its time is messed up due to a (circular) buffer that wasn't filling fast enough. This is what causes these repetitions. If I can hear well, a second track (the voice on the other side of the phone?) is covering some of the repetitions so you would have to work on two tracks separately and mix them in the end.

The second problem is that the audio is over-compressed (data compression) and has lost its high frequency components but there's also audio compression that's brought up the already existing noise. Talking of noise, you can hear clicks in it and I believe you could use those as indications of where audio chunks have been stuck together (as a result of delays).

If I tried to tackle this, I'd start by editing out the repetitions (where the voice glitches), then I'd remove as much noise as possible without ruining the voice further. I'd use the clicks as guidelines and try to see which part goes where. This is kinda like solving an audio puzzle though. You have bits of audio shifted around and you're trying to find where they go. It would take a lot of time, even for someone with trained ears and it's very tedious work. Unfortunately I don't think there is a fast/easy way.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer (it's very well expained). I can't upvote (reputation) and I will let this question open for a little while to try to get as many opinion as possible.

Comment: Yeah, you should.There might be people more knowledgeable than me in here that could give you a a better answer. There might even be specialized software that I'm not aware of. Definitely worth keeping it open.